# Why the error probability is given by this expression?

Tags: digital-communications

I have seen this equation:

$$
\Pr({\epsilon})  = Q({\sqrt{2E_b/N_0}}) \,.
$$

where these definitions hold:

$$N_0/2  - the \ spectral \ density \ of \ white \ noise$$ 
$$E_b = PT_b - the \ energy \ per \ transmitted \ bit$$ 
$$P - Power $$
$$T_b - the \ time\ the \ bit\ transmitted \ in$$

Q - is ([this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function)) function, how do I derive this equation?

Comment: Your error probability expression is incorrect; the square-root sign needs to extend over $N_0$. You can find a derivation of the correct expression in a thread titled Antipodal BER - help" on http://groups.google.com and also [here](http://www.dsplog.com/2007/08/05/bit-error-probability-for-bpsk-modulation/).

Comment: "corrected,thanks"  Good. Did you find what you needed in the material I referred you to?  For a lot more detailed analysis, you may want to read the notes on _matched filters_ found [here](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/spring11/NewLectures.html)

Comment: Great material; thanks for making it available. I would also recommend Lecture 3 Appendix A for what I found to be the most important "missing link" in communication theory: how the continuous-time "waveform channel" maps to the discrete-time "vector channel." That is, how does the waveform observed by a receiver over a symbol period map to a discrete decision problem? Although a bit tough to read, my favorite treatment is the classic [Wozencraft and Jacobs](http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Communication-Engineering-John-Wozencraft/dp/0881335541/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1328406756&sr=8-1).

Comment: The URL given in my previous comment has been changed by the powers that be. The materials referred to are available at [this corrected location](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/sp2011/NewLectures.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A whole chapter of a book can be written to answer the "Why" in this question but the
short answer is that if the signals used are an *antipodal* signal set (meaning 
bits $0$ and $1$ are transmitted using signals $s_0(t)$ and $s_1(t)$ respectively
where $s_1(t) = -s_0(t)$ and the signals are of duration $T$ and energy $E$,
then with *matched filtering*, the receiver makes a decision that $0$ was transmitted
or a $1$ was transmitted according as the *sample value* from the matched filter
is positive or negative.  The sample value is a random variable $X$ whose
distribution is $\mathcal N\left(\pm \sqrt{E}, N_0/2\right)$ depending on whether
a $0$ or a $1$ was transmitted. If $X$ has mean $-\sqrt{E}$ when a $1$ is transmitted,
then the probability of error is
$$\begin{align*}
P_{e,1} &= P\{X > 0 \mid 1~\text{transmitted}\}\\
&= P\left\{\mathcal N\left(-\sqrt{E}, N_0/2\right) > 0\right\}\\
&= Q\left(\frac{0 - \left(-\sqrt{E}\right)}{\sqrt{N_0/2}}\right)\\
&= Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{2E}{N_0}}\right).
\end{align*}$$
Similarly, $X$ has mean $\sqrt{E}$ when a $0$ is transmitted,
and so the probability of error is
$$\begin{align*}
P_{e,0} &= P\{X < 0 \mid 0~\text{transmitted}\}\\
&= P\left\{\mathcal N\left(\sqrt{E}, N_0/2\right) < 0\right\}\\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{0 -\sqrt{E}}{\sqrt{N_0/2}}\right)\\
&= \Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{2E}{N_0}}\right)\\
&= Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{2E}{N_0}}\right).
\end{align*}$$
Finally, using the law of total probability, the probability of error is
$$P_e = P_{e,0}P\{0~\text{transmitted}\}
+ P_{e,1}P\{1~\text{transmitted}\} = Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{2E}{N_0}}\right)$$
regardless of the probabilities of transmitting $0$'s and $1$'s.
For more details such as *why* the matched filters outputs
are as stated above, see, for example, [this lecture 
note](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/sp2011/Newlectures/Lecture03.pdf) and 
[this one](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/sp2011/Newlectures/Lecture04.pdf)
of mine.